# How to parse an XML date with Zulu time in Android?

Tags: android, datetime, xml-parsing, iso8601

How can I parse a standard XML date in Android that is formatted according to the ISO standard? Example:

```
2012-12-13T12:34:56.678Z
```

Note how the time zone is given as "Z" (Zulu time).

`SimpleDateFormat` does not recognize the `Z`, and when I try to use the XML packages, I get an exception that they are not included.

> DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found

Am I missing something? I'm assuming it should be pretty simple and straightforward to parse and format an ISO date.

In JavaScript, we would write:

```
var isoDateString = new Date().toISOString(); //2012-12-13T12:34:56.678Z
var isoDate = new Date(isoDateString);
```

Answer (score -1):

See Android reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

One could also always use java regular expression parsing to grab the components of the DTG, but that is not recommended if the Android API provides this functionality.

Comment: The Android API, unfortunately, does not provide this functionality. In the date formatting string, `Z` does not denote the ISO 8601 time zone, but the RFC 822 time zone. RFC 822 does not know the "Z" shortcut for "Zulu" time = UTC, which is used by ISO 8601. The ISO 8601 time zone is denoted by an `X` in the formatting string, but that is not supported by Android. Please see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone

The pattern given in the Android reference does not correspond to the ISO 8601 date format.